# How set cron task for web page

Tags: 16.04, apache2, cron

Hello i want set few cron taks on my VPS but i dont know exactly how this set in config.

e.g. for web page /var/www/example.com/public_html/test.php for every 5 minutes

From what I read, it should be as like this

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/example.com/public_html/test.php
```

But I want to make sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a method to do this. You can also do this from /etc/cron.d or /etc/crontab

But it depends on what test.php does. If the result of this is to print something to the screen or to a website... not going to work. If this sets a setting on the Ubuntu server sure it will work.

I would advice to add a log behind the command. That will make tracing problems easier.

```
*/5 * * * * /var/www/example.com/public_html/test.php >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1
```